# How do I go back to get Force Push on Zeffo after advancing, not knowing I needed it?

Tags: star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

So, I’m on Zeffo and am at a point where I should already have air push (it’s where you fight the tomb guardian. The first time?) and didn’t realize there was somewhere else I needed to go. I decided to look up a hint because I’ve been trying to make this jump across this space forever and found that I needed force push to push a skungus into a wall to get something. Only thing is that, that was a whiiiile ago and I can’t find a way back because of the air flow that was used with those platforms that gets you to this location. Does anyone know how to get back there?

I know this all sounds dumb. I’m not a gamer outside of minecraft but have been wanting to expand my horizons. So, please don’t be too harsh with me and maybe explain it as if to a child because I’m very dumb lol.

Comment: This seems to be the solution: https://answers.ea.com/t5/Other-STAR-WARS-Games/Stuck-in-quot-Seek-the-Eye-of-the-Storm-quot-on-Zeffo-without/m-p/8481781/highlight/true#M61637